# Official abbreviations for CS conferences

Tags: journals, conference, computer-science

Some journals like to abbreviate journal names in the papers they publish, and the AMS maintains [a list of abbreviated journal names](http://www.ams.org/msnhtml/serials.pdf%20bgb) for those who need them. Is there a similar resource for conferences (in computer science)?

EDIT: to clarify, I'm not looking for acronyms (SODA, STOC, ICALP), but rather for something like "Proc. 6th Ann. ACM-SIAM Symp. Discrete Algorithms".

Comment: usually I just take the .bib source of the paper whether its abbreviated or not

Comment: @seteropere: I usually use unabbreviated citations, but I'm told to shorten a submission and I'd rather sacrifice unimportant parts like these before I modify the actual text.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any *comprehensive* list of abbreviations for CS conferences. One way to see many abbreviations is through CS conference listings and ranking. For example, [here](http://core.edu.au/cms/images/downloads/conference/08sort%20acronymERA2010_conference_list.pdf) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_science_conferences). The most obvious way is googling the name of the conference then checking the conference website.

Comment: I didn't see the edit which seems different from what I was trying to answer.

Comment: I think your answer is fine. If the conference web site uses the abbreviation itself, then it's official.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no such resource, and even if it existed, it would not be very useful.

In general, people do not know the full names of the conference, only their acronyms. The full names tend to change slightly every now and then, while the acronyms are much more stable.

You can safely write pretty much anything that resembles the correct name, as long as you include the acronym. You can often save some space by removing useless words such as "Annual", "International", "ACM", "IEEE", etc.

For example, *"Proc. 6th Symposium on Discrete Algorithms (SODA)"* would be perfectly fine and unambiguous.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be useful? Some journals have a misguided official policy of not using conference acronyms, and it would be good to have a standard set of abbreviations of conferences to use in these journals.

Comment: Removing "Annual" and "International" might be OK if you really have to save space, but it's better not to remove the "ACM" or "IEEE", since knowing the sponsor makes the conference easier to track down.

Comment: @Anonymous: "IEEE" isn't on the cover title of [the Proceedings](http://ieee-focs.org/images/FOCScover.gif) for the FOCS conference. How do you justify putting it in?

Comment: @Peter Shor: If it's not in the title, one certainly shouldn't modify the title to include it, but it's worth listing separately then ("Foundations of Computer Science 1997, IEEE Computer Society, ...").  For really major conferences it's not such a big deal, but minor conferences can be difficult to track down, and even major conferences may be unfamiliar to people in other fields.

Comment: I disagree with @AnonymousMathematician; if the society isn't named in the title, _don't_ add it to the title. Report the title literally.  I rare cases that Google doesn't find the correct proceedings as the first hit, you should definitely include the publisher in the citation (for example, Springer), but not in the title.

Comment: @JeffE: That's exactly what I meant by listing it separately (but not modifying the title to include it).  I meant the "IEEE Computer Society" as being the publisher, not a continuation of the title.